# Django post_save and south migrations

Tags: django, signals, django-south

I have a `post_save` signal for all objects (not only of my app) and in it I create a `SignalInfo` (this model is from my app) object, put info about created/edited object into it and save it. It worked fine until I started using South migrations.

The problem is that when I do `syncdb` now, tables for my app are not created (they will be after `./manage.py migrate`), but new objects like `auth.permission` are being created during `syncdb` and my signal tries to create `SignalInfo` object but it can't because tables for my app are not ready and I have DatabaseError.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `SignalInfo` creation code in a `try...except` block so the error won't interfere. The only side-effect would be that the initial models created by `syncdb` won't have `SignalInfo` objects associated with them.